# Ubuntu - Eclipse & Netbeans alternative

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans

I'm a php developer and I'm looking for an alternative to eclipse and netbeans.
Both don't run great on Ubuntu 11.04.

Any recommendations?

Comment: You need the Sun JDK to run them usably on Ubuntu. The default OpenJDK Java isn't very speedy with Netbeans or Eclipse.

Comment: This applies for every Java-based IDE, also PhpStorm (The one mentioned by OZ_ below) too.

Comment: @mario, is this still the case?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, Indeed it runs rather smoothly with the newer OpenJDK 7, which is much closer to the Oracle JDK 7. Not sure if that's in the 11.04 repositories thouh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)

Very smart IDE, PHP+css+JS, Inspections (it's **very** useful thing), smart autocomplete, plugins (svn, git, github, remote deployment, vim, sql-dialects...) and many other features.

Comment: Its commercial, but I like it :) Note the comment above.

Comment: well... EAP-versions can be used free for very long time (I was at EAP in 6 months :)), and 50% discount can be used until 30 april.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a dupe on that topic: 
[Best PHP IDE for Linux / Gnome ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118808/best-php-ide-for-linux-gnome) 
(It's quite outdated, and I'm refusing to closevote; so just a link.)

If you run on 11.04 already, you might find a suitable package of [**KDevelop 4.2**](http://kdevelop.org/), which added more robust PHP support. As a native app it's obviously more speedy.